# Объясните, пожалуйста в чем ошибка в коде для задачи

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Условие задачи: На сковородку одновременно можно положить k котлет. Каждую котлету нужно с каждой стороны обжаривать m минут непрерывно. За какое наименьшее время удастся поджарить с обеих сторон n котлет? Ниже код, который я написал

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int k, m, n;
    cin >> k >> m >> n;
    if (n<=k) cout << m*2 << endl;
    else
        if (n%k==0) cout << (n/k)*(m*2) << endl;
    else
        cout << (1+(n/k))*(m*2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вводятся 3 числа: k, m и n. Все числа не превосходят 32000.

Пример: на входе `1 5 1` на выходе `10`.

Comment: Данные на входе какие? Ожидаемые и актуальные данные на выходе?

Comment: Вводятся 3 числа: k, m и n. Все числа не превосходят 32000. Пример: на входе 1 5 1 на выходе 10

Comment: что ваш алгоритм выдает на `1 5 1`? Почему думаете, что он не работает?

Comment: Выдает 10, но проверяющая программа на некоторых тестах,  говорит, что выведен неверный ответ

Comment: на каких тестах, есть данные на входе для них?

Comment: К сожалению, другие данные, которые подаются на вход неизвестны

Answer (score 5):

Есть детская задача: как за 3 минуты пожарить 3 котлеты, если на прожарку одной стороны уходит 1 минута, и на сковородку за раз помещается 2 котлеты?

Правильный ответ — пожарить 1-ю и 2-ю котлеты с одной стороны, затем 1-ю со второй стороны вместе с 3-й с первой стороны и наконец 2-ю и 3-ю со второй стороны.

Ваш алгоритм выведет в ответ ошибочные 4 минуты вместо трех.

Полагаю, нужно делить на емкость сковороды `k` не количество котлет `n`, а количество сторон котлет (`2*n`).

Тогда формула расчета времени для `n >= k` будет:

```
var t = Math.Ceiling(2.0 * n / k) * m;
```

`Math.Ceiling()` - это функция округления вверх в C#. В плюсах не помню, как правильно записать, но можно и через условие делимости без остатка, как у вас и написано:

```
int main()
{
    int k, m, n;
    cin >> k >> m >> n;
    if (n <= k) cout << m * 2 << endl
    if (2 * n % k == 0)
       cout << (2 * n / k) * m << endl;
    else
       cout << (1 + (2 * n / k)) * m << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не уверен, что детям самостоятельно стоит жарить котлеты.

Comment: @DiMithras Но определенно стоит решать задачи :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy справедливо, нужно вернуть условие, когда `n < k`

Comment: **Upd:** добавил в код тривиальный случай `n <= k`

Answer (score 1):

Я не оч понимаю где конкретно проблема у вас, возможно в каких то вещах, специфичных для C++, но я бы решил задачу чуть попроще (хоть и принцип тот же)

```
int k = 3, m = 2, n = 17;

int times = n / k + (n % k == 0 ? 0 : 1);
int time = times * m * 2;

Console.WriteLine(time);
```

Код на C# легко подкрутите как надо в C++

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: задача прошла тесты?

Comment: `n = 3`, `k = 2`, `m = 1`. Ваш ответ - `4`. Правильный ответ - `3`.

Answer (score 0):

Как жарить котлеты быстрее всего?

Если котлет нет (*n = 0*), то можно пожарить в ноль заходов.

Если котлет мало (*n ≤ k*), то жарить придётся в два захода. Сперва одну сторону всех котлет, затем вторую. Ясно что быстрее нельзя. Даже для одной котлеты нужны два захода.

Если котлет много, жарим все с одной стороны, затем все со второй стороны. Будет одна жарка общая: сколько-то котлет жарятся с первой стороны, оставшиеся места заняты котлетами на второй стороне. Эта схема самая быстрая потому что во всех заходах кроме последнего сковорода занята полностью. Число нужных заходов *2n / k* округлённое вверх. В коде ниже выражение `(2 * n + k - 1) / k` как раз его и вычисляет:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int k, m, n;
    std::cin >> k >> m >> n;

    int r;
    if (n == 0) {
        r = 0;
    } else if (n <= k) {
        r = 2;
    } else {
        r = (2 * n + k - 1) / k;
    }
    std::cout << m * r << '\n';
}
```